# Macro average (iterate over classes) in custom training loop - tensorflow

Tags: for-loop, graph, tensorflow2.0

I am using a custom training loop. The task is a multi-label multi-class classification, i.e. I have multiple classes I want to predict and each class admits multiple labels. `loss` has dimensions `batch_size, no_classes`, as said before each col in `no_classes` is a multi-label classification task. The following code works when `@tf.function` is commented out, however once graph mode is on, this is not working since iterating over tensor is not allowed in graph mode. Would anyone be able to suggest how I can rewrite the code below so that it works in graph mode?

```
items_loss_list = []
for item in range(loss.shape[1]):
    values, _ = tf.unique(y[:, item])


    item_macro_average = tf.reduce_mean(
        [
            tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.gather_nd(
                    loss[:, item],
                    indices=tf.cast(tf.where(y[:, item] == v), tf.int32),
                )
            )
            for v in values
        ]
    )
    items_loss_list.append(item_macro_average)
```

I also tried:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
while_condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, len(values))
item_score_avg = []
def body(i):
    item_score_avg.append(
        tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.gather_nd(
                loss[:, item],
                indices=tf.cast(tf.where(y[:, item] == values[i]), tf.int32),
            )
        )
    )
    return [tf.add(i, 1)]
tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [i])
items_loss_list.append(tf.reduce_mean(item_score_avg))
```

But this is not working either in graph mode. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain in words what this is calculating? You want the `mean` of `loss`?

Comment: I want to compute the macro average of the loss (per classification task, a classification task corresponds to a column of the loss). The label ground truth for computing the macro average is in y. I am using the list comprehension with 'for v in values' because in the macro average each class is averaged separately and then the per class averages are averaged.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [`map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) solves the problem. `items_macro_average` is a list collecting the macro average loss per task.

```
items_macro_average = []
for item in range(loss.shape[1]):
    values, _ = tf.unique(y[:, item])
    item_macro_average = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.map_fn(
            fn=lambda v: tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.gather_nd(
                    loss[:, item],
                    indices=tf.cast(tf.where(y[:, item] == v), tf.int32),
                )
            ),
            elems=values,
        )
    )
    items_macro_average.append(item_macro_average)
```